# Why does Coq object to the following PairUsualDecidableTypeFull module type?

Tags: coq

In Coq.Structures.EqualitiesFacts, there is a convenient `PairUsualDecidableType` module type for building a `UsualDecidableType` module from the cartesian product of two others.

It seems that there is no corresponding `PairUsualDecidableTypeFull` module type for doing the same with `UsualDecidableTypeFull`s.

I tried to create one, beginning as follows:

```
Module PairUsualDecidableTypeFull(D1 D2:UsualDecidableTypeFull) <: UsualDecidableTypeFull.

  Definition t := (D1.t * D2.t)%type.
  Definition eq := @eq t.
  Instance eq_equiv : Equivalence eq := _.
  Definition eq_refl : forall x : t, x = x. Admitted.
  Definition eq_sym : forall x y : t, x = y -> y = x. Admitted.
  Definition eq_trans : forall x y z : t, x = y -> y = z -> x = z. Admitted.
  Definition eq_dec : forall x y, { eq x y }+{ ~eq x y }. Admitted.
  Definition eqb : t -> t -> bool. Admitted.
  Definition eqb_eq : forall x y : t, eqb x y = true <-> x = y. Admitted.

End PairUsualDecidableTypeFull.
```

but Coq complains that:

```
Signature components for label eq_refl do not match: the body of definitions differs.
```

I do not understand what "signature components" means. Given that the output of `Print UsualDecidableTypeFull` includes:

```
Definition eq_refl : forall x : t, @Logic.eq t x x.
```

the *type* of `eq_refl` at least looks right. What else could be wrong?

I am a total amateur and extremely new to Coq, running version 8.9.0. Perhaps what I'm trying to do doesn't make sense for some reason; the fact that the standard libraries include `PairUsualDecidableType` but not `PairUsualDecidableTypeFull` makes me a little suspicious I've missed something.

Any guidance would be most welcome, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the standard library is known to be incomplete. Thus, the fact that one particular definition/lemma/module is not provided does not mean that it should not be there. And it is even more true for modules, since the module system of Coq is little used.

Concerning your problem, in Coq, the boundary between `Module` and `Module Type` is thin. In particular, you can have definitions in `Module Type`, and not only declarations (I am not sure that these terms "definition" and "declaration" are the right words to use here, but I hope it is at least understandable). For instance,

```
Module Type Sig.
  Parameter n : nat.
  Definition plus x y := x + y.
End Sig.
```

is a signature declaring a field `n` of type `nat` and defining a field `plus` as the addition of natural numbers. When writing a module that must comply with this signature, you can implement the declarations as you wish, as long as types correspond, but for definitions, you must basically write exactly the same body as in the signature. For instance, you can write:

```
Module M <: Sig.
  Definition n := 3.
  Definition plus x y := x + y.
End M.
```

You can observe which fields are declarations and which are definitions using `Print`: declarations appear as `Parameter` and definitions appear as `Definition` (but the actual body of the definition is not printed, which is admittedly confusing). In your case, `eq`, `eq_equiv`, `eq_refl`, `eq_sym` and `eq_trans` are all definitions in `UsualDecidableTypeFull`, so you have no choice for their implementation, you must define `eq` as `Logic.eq`, `eq_equiv` as `eq_equivalence` (cf. the definitions in [Equalities](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Structures.Equalities.html)), etc. When using `Admitted` to implement `eq_refl`, you are using a body different from the one given in the signature. Your module definition is thus rejected with the message `the body of definitions differs`.

If I come back to your initial problem of writing a functor `PairUsualDecidableTypeFull`, by digging into [Equalities](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Structures.Equalities.html) and [EqualitiesFacts](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Structures.EqualitiesFacts.html), I wrote this implementation that reuses as much as possible existing components of the standard library.

```
Module DT_to_Full (D:DecidableType') <: DecidableTypeFull.
    Include Backport_DT (D).
    Include HasEqDec2Bool.
End DT_to_Full.

Module PairUsualDecidableTypeFull (D1 D2:UsualDecidableTypeFull)
  <: UsualDecidableTypeFull.

    Module M := PairUsualDecidableType D1 D2.
    Include DT_to_Full (M).
End PairUsualDecidableTypeFull.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, very illuminating, and most satisfying. Even though you say the module system is little used, do you think it would be worth submitting a pull request to the Coq project submitting your `PairUsualDecidableTypeFull` so that it will be available in a future version of Coq.Structures.EqualitiesFacts?

Comment: Such small contribution that consistently improves the stdlib has indeed a chance to be accepted, I think. See [this page](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/9113) about the current status of contributing to the stdlib. But be prepared for a potential long discussion, such pull requests tend to be passionate (unlikely in this case).

Comment: I see; thanks for sharing the guidelines, which I will study later. Actually I was suggesting that you make the contribution since you deserve the credit. However if you prefer, I will happily do it (explaining that it is your work, not mine). Would you be OK with my doing this?

Comment: No problem, go ahead.

Comment: Great, I'll paste a link here once I have.

Comment: Cool. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work around this by simply "wrapping" Coq's `UsualDecidableTypeFull` by defining:

```
Module Type UDTFW <: UsualDecidableType.

  Parameter t : Type.
  Definition eq := @Logic.eq t.
  Definition eq_equiv : Equivalence eq := _.
  Parameter eq_refl : forall x : t, x = x.
  Parameter eq_sym : forall x y : t, x = y -> y = x.
  Parameter eq_trans : forall x y z : t, x = y -> y = z -> x = z.
  Parameter eq_dec : forall x y, { @Logic.eq t x y }+{ ~@Logic.eq t x y }.
  Parameter eqb : t -> t -> bool.
  Parameter eqb_eq : forall x y : t, eqb x y = true <-> x = y.

End UDTFW.
```

together with:

```
Module Make_UDTFW (X : UsualDecidableTypeFull) <: UDTFW.

  Definition t := X.t.
  Definition eq := X.eq.
  Definition eq_equiv := X.eq_equiv.
  Definition eq_refl := X.eq_refl.
  Definition eq_sym := X.eq_sym.
  Definition eq_trans := X.eq_trans.
  Definition eq_dec := X.eq_dec.
  Definition eqb := X.eqb.
  Definition eqb_eq := X.eqb_eq.

End Make_UDTFW.
```

Having introduced this bizarre-looking extra level of indirection at the module level, the defintion of `PairUsualDecidableTypeFull` in the question actually works, except using `UDTFW` everywhere intead of `UsualDecidableTypeFull`.

This rather ugly workaround turns out to suffice for my purposes but I'd be very interested to understand what the real issue is here.